# Remove dataframe that has not yet appeared in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:
df1:

```
name country gender
john cn      1
joe  us      0
cici cn      1
lily us      0

df2:

    name country gender
    john cn      1
    joe  us      0
```

I want to get a df3, which is a dataframe that appears in df1, but not in df2. looks as below

```
cici cn 1
lily us 0
```

is there anyway to do this in one line of pandas

Answer (score 1):

You can try `merge` with `indicator`

```
df1_sub = df1.merge(df2, indicator=True,how='left').loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only'].drop('_merge',axis=1)
df1_sub
Out[143]: 
   name country  gender
2  cici      cn       1
3  lily      us       0
```